Spring Webflux - Azure Redis giving error: readAddress(..) failed: Connection reset by peer
I'm not sure where I'm gonig wrong.
I can connect with redis cli, but not with Spring Boot Webflux.
My code:
@Bean
    @Primary
    fun reactiveRedisConnectionFactory(): ReactiveRedisConnectionFactory {

        // Configure Redis standalone configuration
        val config = RedisStandaloneConfiguration()
        config.hostName = redisHostName
        config.port = redisPort
        config.setPassword(redisPassword) // Use the token as password

        // Create socket options
        val socketOptions = SocketOptions.builder()
            .keepAlive(true)
            .build()

        // Create client options
        val clientOptions = ClientOptions.builder()
            .socketOptions(socketOptions)
            .build()

        // Create Lettuce client configuration with authentication details
        val clientConfig = LettucePoolingClientConfiguration.builder()
            .commandTimeout(Duration.ofSeconds(60))
            .clientResources(DefaultClientResources.create())
            .clientOptions(clientOptions)
            .poolConfig(buildLettucePoolConfig())
            .useSsl()
            .build()

        // Create Lettuce connection factory
        return LettuceConnectionFactory(config, clientConfig).apply {
            afterPropertiesSet()
        }
    }

    protected fun buildLettucePoolConfig(): GenericObjectPoolConfig<Any> {
        val poolConfig = GenericObjectPoolConfig<Any>()
        poolConfig.maxTotal = 100
        poolConfig.maxIdle = 50
        poolConfig.minIdle = 50
        poolConfig.setMaxWait(Duration.ofMillis(60000))
        poolConfig.timeBetweenEvictionRuns = Duration.ofMillis(60000)
        poolConfig.minEvictableIdleDuration = Duration.ofMillis(60000)
        return poolConfig
    }
}

spring.data.redis.host=hostname.redis.cache.windows.net
spring.data.redis.password=access-key
spring.data.redis.port=6380

The error I get is:
org.springframework.data.redis.RedisConnectionFailureException: Unable to connect to Redis
Caused by: org.springframework.data.redis.connection.PoolException: Could not get a resource from the pool
Caused by: io.lettuce.core.RedisConnectionException: Unable to connect to hostname.redis.cache.windows.net/:6380
Caused by: io.netty.channel.unix.Errors$NativeIoException: readAddress(..) failed: Connection reset by peer
Not sure where I'm gonig wrong. Any ideas?

You are using the SSL port (6380). I think you need to use spring.data.redis.ssl.enabled config property as well.

Thank you. Sees to help! Before I was doing just this,     val clientConfig = LettucePoolingClientConfiguration.builder()
// maximum time allowed for a Redis command to execute before the operation is considered timed out.
.commandTimeout(Duration.ofSeconds(60))
.clientResources(clientResources)
.clientOptions(clusterClientOptions)
.poolConfig(buildLettucePoolConfig())
.useSsl()
.build() - but with that, the intermittent error I kept getting seems to have gone.
